# Why i'm able to print BARCODE EAN13 but not BARCODE ITF using bytes on my Android/JAVA app?

Tags: java, android, thermal-printer, escpos

I have a thermal print that works fine when i try to print a EAN13 format barcode, this is my code:

```
mmOutputStream.write(PrinterCommandsOfi.HW_INIT);

String code = "3226041809";// entradaObj.getEan13();

// Align Bar Code()
mmOutputStream.write(TXT_ALIGN_CT);
mmOutputStream.write(BARCODE_HEIGHT);
mmOutputStream.write(BARCODE_WIDTH);
mmOutputStream.write(BARCODE_FONT_B);
mmOutputStream.write(BARCODE_TXT_BLW);
mmOutputStream.write(BARCODE_ITF);
// mmOutputStream.write(BARCODE_EAN13);
mmOutputStream.write(code.getBytes());
mmOutputStream.write(CTL_LF);

byte[] arrayOfByte1 = { 27, 33, 0 };
byte[] format = { 27, 33, 0 };

mmOutputStream.write(format);
mmOutputStream.write(TXT_ALIGN_CT);
```

I'm able to print with my **commented line** with EAN13 just fine, but when i try to print with ITF(Interleaved 2 of 5 ) i get nothing, what i'm doing wrong?

This is my helper command class to print:

```
// Barcode format
public static final byte[] BARCODE_TXT_OFF = {0x1d,0x48,0x00}; // HRI printBarcode chars OFF
public static final byte[] BARCODE_TXT_ABV = {0x1d,0x48,0x01}; // HRI printBarcode chars above
public static final byte[] BARCODE_TXT_BLW = {0x1d,0x48,0x02}; // HRI printBarcode chars below
public static final byte[] BARCODE_TXT_BTH = {0x1d,0x48,0x03}; // HRI printBarcode chars both above and below
public static final byte[] BARCODE_FONT_A  = {0x1d,0x66,0x00}; // Font type A for HRI printBarcode chars
public static final byte[] BARCODE_FONT_B  = {0x1d,0x66,0x01}; // Font type B for HRI printBarcode chars
public static final byte[] BARCODE_HEIGHT  = {0x1d,0x68,0x64}; // Barcode Height [1-255]
public static final byte[] BARCODE_WIDTH   = {0x1d,0x77,0x03}; // Barcode Width  [2-6]
public static final byte[] BARCODE_UPC_A   = {0x1d,0x6b,0x00}; // Barcode type UPC-A
public static final byte[] BARCODE_UPC_E   = {0x1d,0x6b,0x01}; // Barcode type UPC-E
public static final byte[] BARCODE_EAN13   = {0x1d,0x6b,0x02}; // Barcode type EAN13
public static final byte[] BARCODE_EAN8    = {0x1d,0x6b,0x03}; // Barcode type EAN8
public static final byte[] BARCODE_CODE39  = {0x1d,0x6b,0x04}; // Barcode type CODE39
public static final byte[] BARCODE_ITF     = {0x1d,0x6b,0x05}; // Barcode type ITF
public static final byte[] BARCODE_NW7     = {0x1d,0x6b,0x06}; // Barcode type NW7
```

and this is a link from a good manual for ESC/POS for thermal printers:

https://www.sparkag.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/ESC_POS-AK912-English-Command-Specifications-V1.4.pdf

Comment: Looking at the pdf manual, can you check how many digits are in your data as ITF appears to need an odd number.

Comment: I'm trying to print this number 3226041809

Comment: There are likely to be two mistakes. First, you haven't set the barcode length information (indicated by nL in the document). Second, the ITF barcode data must have odd digits, but you have specified even digits. According to the documentation, this printer always prints the ITF barcode as having a check digit. It seems that the application needs to specify odd digit data that does not include the check digit, as the check digit is automatically calculated and added by the printer.

Comment: @kunif can you make a example for me?

Comment: The barcode data presented in the source code is not the EAN13 of the title or question, so if you really want to print the EAN13, use the correct EAN13 code. Then insert the data representing the data length of 1byte between `.write(BARCODE_ITF);` and `.write(code.getBytes());`. You can probably print with it. Please try. And it is also necessary for the side that reads the barcode to respond. You may need to configure the barcode scanner not to notify you of the ITF check digit, or let it notify you including the check digit so that your application removes the last digit.

Comment: @kunif i don't want the EAN13 i want ITF, the problem is that i can print EAN13 but not ITF

Comment: EAN13 is written in various parts of the question, and it looks like you want to print an ITF barcode with the same value as the 13-digit numeric string of that EAN13. For example, to prevent such misreading, please add the exact number of digits of the data you want to print by ITF and the internal information division format (company code, product number, quantity, lot number, etc.) to the question.